# Chrome Device Mode changes

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When opening dev tools, the device mode Icon is often not available.
In trying to determine why, it appears that it's use is now limited to a single tab in the browser. It used to work on as many as you liked.

It's extremely problematic,
as I often have several responsive pages that need comparison.

Anyone know why Google is limiting that function?

I used that an average of 8 hours a day for the past year and a half,
and suddenly it's unavailable for most of the tabs I have open.

does anyone have a work around?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: I can open many tabs with device mode preview on on my Chrome (58.0.3029.96), so it must be a problem with your installation not with the Chrome. Restart your computer?